# Transferring data between classes and forms

Tags: c#, class, user-interface, nullreferenceexception

long time reader, first time poster:

I've been trying to pick up C# and writing a game program, but am hung up on how to transfer data to my GUI from logic classes and visa-versa. Transferring strings would be ideal, and it seems pretty simple, so I was hoping someone could help me out.

In the most basic case, I'd like to know why this isnt working:

```
namespace MyGame
{
    public partial class GameWindow : Form
    {
        public LogicClass gameLogic;
        public GameWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    private void startButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string toDisplay = gameLogic.getString();
        this.label1.Text = toDisplay;
    }
}
```

and the game logic class

```
namespace MyGame
{
    public class LogicClass
    {
        public string getString()
        {
            return "success!";
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried for a few days now to find out why I get a nullReferenceException at line

```
string toDisplay = gameLogic.getString();
```

this isn't the end result of what I'd like to do, of course, but if somebody could explain to me what's going on here and how I could pass a string from a different class to the GUI I think I'll be able to get a foothold into how to do the rest of the things that I'd like. I've seen a lot of things on transferring data from forms to other forms, but I can't find what I need about classes to forms. I know it can be done; its just too simple not to be possible. Can anyone help me out?

Thanks!
Jake

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your data transfer logic is fine, the reason for the exception is gameLogic is never instantiated. You could replace `public LogicClass gameLogic;` with `public LogicClass gameLogic = new LogicClass();`

Or add `gameLogic = new LogicClass();` in the constructor after the call to InitializeComponent().

Comment: perfect. Thats exactly what I was missing. Sorry for the newbie question!

Answer (score 0):

You can make a file an object and use it through that;

```
LoginLg loginLg = new LoginLg();
```

You can now use this to send it to an individual subroutine:

```
loginLg.LoginCheck(username, password);
```

Answer (score -1):

Or you could define the `getstring` method as `Static`.

```
Public Static String getstring()
```

This will help you call the method without instantiating the class.